# Why do I need to add a huge delay to switch channels in ADC on atmega2560?

Tags: c, microcontroller, atmega, adc

I have this code that takes multiple adc conversions and send them on serial, if I don't add a 3 ms delay after set_ADMUX() the ADC sample is not the correct one for the channel, but I think it's a too large delay to be normal, here's the code:

```
//setup adc
void set_adc(void) {
  ADCSRA = (( 1<<ADEN ) | ( 1<<ADATE ) | ( 1<<ADIE ) | (1 << ADSC) ); // enable adc, auto trigger, interrupt enable, start first rilevation
  ADCSRB = (( 1<<ADTS2 ) | ( 1<<ADTS0 )); // Timer/Counter 1 Compare Match B 
  ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR); //set Voltage reference to Avcc (5v), left adjust converted value, if this is commented we use AREF
}

//timer for adc conversions
uint16_t ticks;
void set_timer1 ( uint16_t ticks )
{
  TCCR1A  = 0;
  TCCR1B  = 0;
  TCNT1   = 0;
  TIMSK1  = 0;
  TCCR1B  = ( 1 << WGM12 ) ;  // configure for CTC mode 4 OCR1A=TOP
  OCR1A   = ticks;  // set CTC TOP value
  TCCR1B |= ( 1 << CS10 ); // start timer, give it a clock, fcpu/1
}

//set channel for adc
volatile uint8_t i=0;
void set_ADMUX(void){ 
  switch(i){
    case 0:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR);
        break;
    case 1:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX0);
        break;
    case 2:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX1);
        break;
    case 3:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX0) | (1 << MUX1);
        break;
    case 4:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX2);
        break;
    case 5:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX0);
        break;
    case 6:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX1);
        break;
    case 7:
        ADMUX = (1 << REFS0) | (1 << ADLAR) | (1 << MUX2) | (1 << MUX1) | (1 << MUX0);
        break;
  }
}

//adc interrupt
uint32_t key=0x55aa;
volatile uint8_t sample_count=0;
volatile uint8_t send_flag=0;
uint8_t buffull_count=0;
ISR(ADC_vect) {
  while(channel_buffer[i]!=1){
      i++;  
      if(i>=8){
          i=0;
          }
      }
  set_ADMUX();  
  _delay_ms(3);//<-------------------------------------------------------------
  switch(i){
      case 0:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer1[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=1;
        //printf("1");
        break;
      case 1:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer2[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=2;
        //printf("2");
        break;
      case 2:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer3[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=3;
        //printf("3");
        break;
      case 3:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer4[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=4;
        //printf("4");
        break;
      case 4:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer5[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=5;
        //printf("5");
        break;
      case 5:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer6[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=6;
        //printf("6");
        break;
      case 6:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer7[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=7;
        //printf("7");
        break;
      case 7:
        if(mode==1){
            buffer8[sample_count]=ADCH;
            }
        channel=8;
        //printf("8");
        break;
      }
  if(mode==0){  
    printf("%d\n", channel);
    printf("%d\n", ADCH);
    structure.seq++;
    }  
  if(mode==1){sample_count++;}
  if(sample_count==BUFFER_SIZE-1){
        buffull_count++;
        sample_count=0;
        if(buffull_count==num_channels){
            sample_count=0; 
            if(mode==1){
              send_flag=1;
              buffull_count=0;
              }
            }
    }
  i++;
  TIFR1 = ( 1<<OCF1B ); // clear Compare Match B Flag
}
```

I tought about some adc setup problem, or a wrong use of the ISR, but can't find the precise reason, smaller delays won't work

After being told, I reduced the code to only what regards ADC.

I am using atmega 2560, datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Taking a look at the code... Indentation is poor. Notice in `send_bulk()`; a single `return;` at the top would eliminate a level of indent (that you've overdone in the `switch()`.) A 2D array, instead of `buffer1-8` would eliminate swaths of code... This doesn't address your issue, but... Who knows what's hiding in 300 lines of code?

Comment: Similarly, your logic for selecting the input source is odd - you wait for an ADC conversion to complete, and *then* you update the multiplexer before reading the result. You will certainly need a delay between those two actions, at least as long as your configured sampling frequency. Apart from advising you to restructure your program, I would also ask what your ADC sampling period is set to (i.e., how often does TCNT1 reset?)

Comment: so what is the question?   adc takes time to convert this should be (it is) in the datasheet.  if you have a mux in front of the adc, that takes time to settle as well, and is also in the datasheet.  are you questioning the reason for the settling time?  there is no reason for interrupts to learn how the peripheral works. is this question about interrupts?

Comment: the title question is about why is there a delay to settle the mux, but your code has interrupts and there is a ton of it, shouldnt be more than a few handfuls of lines of code to resolve the settling time question (and no interrupts) (maybe a few dozen lines)

Comment: Your source code is barely readable, it is too much and lacks white space. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] with emphasis on "minimal" and "complete". Additionally, please add a link to the data sheet of the specific ATmega you use, and add the conversion time you found therein.

Comment: I reduced the code to adc related parts, I read the datasheet and I believe the timing for the change of multiplexer of the adc is not told, I only know the conversion time for adc sample is 13 clock cycles, and atmega2560 has a 16 mHz cpu. I will try to make a minimal reproducible example but I fear it will cut out unexpected causes of the big time needed for the switching of channels

Comment: Do this step-by-step, and you might find the problem in the course. If so, consider to write an own answer, or to delete the question.

Comment: I will do that, starting from what @lxop remarked, I in fact am using set_ADMUX in an odd way and this could cause some strange behaviours, thanks for your time

Comment: "but I think it's a too large delay to be normal" What sample rate do you expect then? You need to know this before you can use an ADC. To begin with, it matters _a lot_ it is a SAC ADC or a delta sigma. The former are fast but lower resolution and most common in MCUs. The latter are slow but high resolution and sometimes available in MCUs too. Also your code formatting is all over the place, please adopt a conventional code formatting and use the same formatting consistently, if you expect others to read your code. Personally, I can't be bothered to read it in the current state.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my logic, as @lxop noted:

> you wait for an ADC conversion to complete, and then you update the multiplexer before reading the result

I moved the `set_ADMUX` to the end of the ISR and now everything works fine.